Diffusion (heat) equation in axisymmetric form
Can someone help me solve $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$ with boundary conditions $u(0, t) = u_0$ and $u(r \rightarrow \infty, t) = 0$ and with initial condition $u(r>0, 0)=0$ where $0 \leq r < \infty$.
I tried to solve using similarity solution method where I substitute for $u(x, t)=f(\zeta)$ where $\zeta = r/\sqrt{t}$ and this gives $$ f''(\zeta)+ \left(\frac{1}{\zeta}+\frac{\zeta}{2} \right)f' = 0$$Solving this gives an answer with exponential integral function $$f(x)=-C_1 \frac{\operatorname{E_1}\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}{2}+C_2$$But I am not able to apply boundary conditions to this solution since the exponential integral function is not defined at 0.

The fundamental particular solutions of the 2-d rotational symmetric diffusion equation is $$ \partial_t \  f\ - \frac{1}{2} \ \partial_r\ \left( r\  \partial_r  f \right)=0$$  with $$f\ = \  e^{- \lambda^2 \ t  } \  \left(  a  \  J_0\left( \sqrt{2}\  \lambda \ r \right)  + b  \  Y_0\left( \sqrt{2} \ \lambda  \ r\right) \right) .  $$ The series or integral in $\lambda$ to adapt to be zero at $t=0$ and $u(t)$ at $r=0$ is probably not done by a closed finite formula.

@RolandF thank you for your answer! This helps a lot

@KamalAhmadov Your boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
$u(0,0)$ can't be equal to $u_0$ and $0$ simultaneously.

@gpmath sorry if I did not state my initial conditions correctly. The initial condition is $u(r>0, 0)=0$, and the boundary condition is $u(r=0, t)=u_0$ where $ 0 \leq r < \infty$
